# Is it possible to get the main site activity and meta activity together in one SEDE query?

Tags: support, data-explorer, per-site-meta

What I wish to obtain is a neat table displaying these columns from left to right - `"User Name", "Reputation", "Main site posts count", "Meta site posts count"`.

The problem here is that SEDE won't (or at least I think it won't, I may be wrong) be able to count posts from **both** **the meta and main site.** The SEDE site selector allows me to select, for example, "Mathematics" **or** "Mathematics Meta" but **not both at once**.

Of course, I can run SEDE once on the main site and another time on the meta site and then combine the two tables, but (1) I don't know how to combine the two tables, and (2) I hope there's a more efficient method here. Is there a way to combine Main and Meta sites in one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [certainly possible](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/822829/math-users-main-meta), you just need to fully qualify the database names (`[StackExchange.Math].dbo.Users` instead of just `Users`). You'll lose some of the functionality such as easy site switching (note that it's a *Stack Overflow* query) and the magic links for posts and users (I had to build the URL myself).

[image]

For reference, here is the complete query:

```
SELECT 'https://math.stackexchange.com/u/' + CAST(Main.Id AS NVARCHAR)
  + '|' + Main.DisplayName,
  Main.Reputation,
  Main.Total AS '# of posts (main)',
  Meta.Total AS '# of posts (meta)',
  CASE WHEN Meta.Total = 0 THEN NULL
       ELSE ROUND(CAST(Main.Total AS FLOAT) / Meta.Total, 2) END AS 'Ratio'

FROM

(SELECT u.Id, u.DisplayName, u.Reputation, COUNT(*) AS Total
  FROM [StackExchange.Math].dbo.Users AS u
  INNER JOIN [StackExchange.Math].dbo.Posts AS p ON u.Id = p.OwnerUserId
  GROUP BY u.Id, u.DisplayName, u.Reputation) AS Main

INNER JOIN

(SELECT u.Id, COUNT(*) AS Total
  FROM [StackExchange.Math.Meta].dbo.Users AS u
  INNER JOIN [StackExchange.Math.Meta].dbo.Posts AS p ON u.Id = p.OwnerUserId
  GROUP BY u.Id) AS Meta

ON Main.Id = Meta.Id

ORDER BY Main.Reputation DESC
```

Comment: Woah, cool! Thanks! Can you please add a fifth column - "Ratio of main site to meta site post counts" as well? (I know I should have added it into the question originally, but forgot, sorry!)

Comment: Also, an optimization problem for you: currently getting this query to work for another site, say Chemistry SE, will require changing five separate instances of text. Is there any way to store the site name in a global variable at the top of the code so it will need to be changed only once? Many thanks!

Comment: The ratio is easy to add, see the updated answer. I bet you could've done that yourself. For your second comment, you have to do something like [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/784126/) where you build the SQL string dynamically and then execute it. You lose syntax highlighting, that's a tradeoff and as you can see, there are many sites for which the database name doesn't match the URL, so you have to build a lot of exceptions.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it is pretty clear now. "I bet you could've done that yourself" That is one thing I've been really trying to do for the past week. I took the SEDE tutorial this site has, but I still am not sure if it was taught how to do `CASE WHEN Meta.Total = 0 THEN NULL
       ELSE ROUND(CAST(Main.Total AS FLOAT) / Meta.Total, 2) END AS 'Ratio'` in it. Maybe it was but I missed it? Idk, but I still don't feel completely confident doing these queries, so I am trying to learn by example code as much as possible. This code was very helpful for me to learn new things, thanks for that!

Comment: You could've come up with `Main.Total / Meta.Total`; that would have failed for two reasons: Meta.Total can be 0, which leads to a division-by-zero error, and when you divide two integers, you get another integer (that's where the CAST and ROUND are for).